# Package(s) for traffic signs

Tags: packages

I am looking for package(s) that include traffic signs as symbols; I would appreciate if you could let me know if you are familiar with any.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx. As it stands, this is rather a difficult question to tackle. There are lots of sources of symbols, but I'd image that they'd just be images that you could include using `\includegraphics`. Finding an appropriate set of images wouldn't really be on-topic, and including them would be pretty easy. Is there more to it than that? (BTW, road signs are also likely to be country-dependent, so it might be useful to say where you are in the world.)

Comment: Not as such, but according to http://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive you have \octagon from the wasysym font, \largediamond from the MnSymbol font, \BigTriangleDown and \BigTriangleUp from the ifsym font.  You can always create a rectangle using \fbox.

Comment: There is also \dbend from the manfnt font.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments and directions; I am familiar with most of the alternative but I thought someone has already done the hard work and I could just use it for my presentation -although google search didn't return anything useful. Thanks again. I live in the US for now, to answer your question; but my use has nothing to do with the local conventions.

Comment: As already said: You could use `\includegraphics` A nice source is WIkipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Road_signs_by_country

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `bclogo` package ([see documentation at CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/bclogo)) has some nice, colored traffic signs:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this package; although its list of traffic signs seems to be limited, I do like the sight of `\bcpanchant` which was one of the signs I was particularly looking for to use in reports.

Answer (score 9):

There are only a few kinda-traffic-signs in the unicode which look like this:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{symbola.ttf}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{lc}
        \toprule
        Sign & Example\\
        \midrule
        Crossing Lanes & \symbol{"26CC} \\
        Disabled Car & \symbol{"26CD} \\
        Car Sliding & \symbol{"26D0} \\
        Circ.\ Crossing Lanes & \symbol{"26D2} \\
        Chains & \symbol{"26D3} \\
        No Entry & \symbol{"26D4} \\
        Alternate One-Way & \symbol{"26D5} \\
        Two-Way & \symbol{"26D6}\symbol{"26D7} \\
        Left Lane Merge & \symbol{"26D8}\symbol{"26D9} \\
        Drive Slow Sign & \symbol{"26DA} \\
        Down-Pointing Triangle & \symbol{"26DB} \\
        Left Close Entry & \symbol{"26DC} \\
        Restr.\ Left Entry & \symbol{"26E0} \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The font `quivira.otf` has some of them, too, which look similar. You can have a look for more fonts [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/26d4/fontsupport.htm).

If you are able to use Xe- or LuaLaTeX, you could search for a [font like these](http://www.fontspace.com/category/highway) and include the symbols to your document.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; it gives me at least some options. Sorry if I can't vote up; thanks again!